# New dependency React native - gradle clean - could not resolve all dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, build.gradle

I've recently added a library to my react-native project. The project was running fine before  adding this dependency. However, when I try tryi to run it now through `react-native run-android` I get this error:

```
File C:\Users\user\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: 
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.onesignal:OneSignal:23.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.onesignal:OneSignal:23.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-onesignal

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 57.711 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Edit: The android emulator is of course running.
After doing som research I figured out that I could try npm uninstall and install, without success. In the build.gradle I have specified my onesignal_app_id, and    `compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:23.0.1'` under dependencies. I therefore tried gradle clean which produced this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-onesignal'.
      > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
         > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Cordova.

I fixed by changing version of gradle from `2.2.3` to `2.3.3`.

Below oneliner for this:

```
sed -i -E 's/com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.[0-9]+/com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3/g' build.gradle
```